# How to transfer 4.4 GB of user images to S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

What would be the best way to transfer 4.4 GB of user images to S3?

I would prefer to somehow directly trasnfer images from my current production server to a S3 bucket and without having to download images to my home mahchine first and then upload it to a S3 bucket.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use http://s3tools.org/s3cmd.

Comment: Thanks. This is excellent. Will definately try this out. 

By the way, how do I accpet an asnwer on Serverfault? I don't see any 'accept' button here.

Comment: You should see white button just below "downvote" arrow of this answer.